# How to sum time in a dataframe

Tags: python, datetime, pandas

I have a dataframe of time data in the format

```
hh:mm:ss
hh:mm:ss
```

(type string)

I need to be able to sum the values (to acquire total time) in a few of the columns.  I'm wondering if anyone has any recommendations on the best way to do this and get the sum in the same format.

Comment: Is the entire thing one string, or each line? Are you just looking to sum each?

Comment: Is it a pandas dataframe? If so, can you add the pandas tag?

Comment: each line is one string

Comment: I am looking to sum each column.  Each column contains about 400 lines of data in the format listed above (hh:mm:ss).  Sorry for any confusion.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can do this using timedelta:

```
import pandas as pd
import datetime

data = {'t1':['01:15:31', 
              '00:47:15'], 
        't2':['01:13:02', 
              '00:51:33']
        }

def make_delta(entry):
    h, m, s = entry.split(':')
    return datetime.timedelta(hours=int(h), minutes=int(m), seconds=int(s))

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df = df.applymap(lambda entry: make_delta(entry))

df['elapsed'] = df['t1'] + df['t2']

In [23]: df
Out[23]:
        t1       t2  elapsed
0 01:15:31 01:13:02 02:28:33
1 00:47:15 00:51:33 01:38:48
```

Edit: I see you need to do this by column, not row.  In that case do the same thing, but:

```
In [24]: df['t1'].sum()
Out[24]: Timedelta('0 days 02:02:46')
```

Comment: Thank you!  any recommendations on how to apply this to only a few specific rows of the dataframe?

Comment: Sure, in the `applymap` line, instead of `df = df.applymap` you can just do `df[['col1', 'col2']] = df[['col1', 'col2']].applymap...`

Answer (score 7):

You can use [`to_timedelta`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.to_timedelta.html) with [`sum`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.sum.html):

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'A': ['18:22:28', '12:15:10']})

df['A'] = pd.to_timedelta(df.A)

print (df)
         A
0 18:22:28
1 12:15:10

print (df.dtypes)
A    timedelta64[ns]
dtype: object

print (df.A.sum())
1 days 06:37:38
```

Comment: `1 days 06:37:38` goes against the requirement of "in the same format". Does `timedelta64` have an equivalent to `strftime`?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe try using `datetime.timedelta`?

```
import re
from datetime import timedelta

_TIME_RE = re.compile(r'(\d+):(\d+):(\d+)')

def parse_timedelta(line):
    # Invalid lines (such as blank) will be considered 0 seconds
    m = _TIME_RE.match(line)
    if m is None:
        return timedelta()
    hours, minutes, seconds = [int(i) for i in m.groups()]
    return timedelta(hours=hours, minutes=minutes, seconds=seconds)

def format_timedelta(delta):
    hours, rem = divmod(delta.seconds + delta.days * 86400, 3600)
    minutes, seconds = divmod(rem, 60)
    return '{:02}:{:02}:{:02}'.format(hours, minutes, seconds)
```

If `data` is a list containing the lines:

```
print(format_timedelta(sum(parse_timedelta(line) for line in data)))
```