# using python or pandas how to sum excel columns which stores data of login time in 00:00:00 format

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I need to add different columns of time to know the total login time using python and pandas [follow this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GWaL9.png)

```
id        time1        time2       total-time
A          01:00:00    01:00:00
B          00:30:00    00:20:00
C          00:40:00    00:30:00
D          00:20:00    00:40:00
E          00:30:00    00:20:00
```

Comment: What is expected output from your sample data?

Answer (score 0):

I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38229357/how-to-sum-time-in-a-dataframe), which seems to be what you are looking for. 
The following is my adaptation to your example:

```
import datetime
def make_delta(entry):
    h, m, s = entry.split(':')
    return datetime.timedelta(hours=int(h), minutes=int(m), seconds=int(s))

df2 = df.set_index('id').applymap(lambda entry: make_delta(entry))

df2['total-time'] = df2['time1'] + df2['time2']
df2.reset_index(drop = False)

    id  time1   time2   total-time
0   A   01:00:00    01:00:00    02:00:00
1   B   00:30:00    00:20:00    00:50:00
2   C   00:40:00    00:30:00    01:10:00
3   D   00:20:00    00:40:00    01:00:00
4   E   00:30:00    00:20:00    00:50:00
```

Hope this works for you

Answer (score 0):

Idea is select all columns without last by [`DataFrame.iloc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.iloc.html), or filter columns by text by [`DataFrame.filter`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.filter.html) or seelct by list, convert to strings if python time object,convert to timedeltas by [`to_timedelta`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.to_timedelta.html) and last `sum` per rows:

```
df['total-time'] = df.iloc[:,1:].astype(str).apply(pd.to_timedelta).sum(axis=1)
print (df)
  id     time1     time2 total-time
0  A  01:00:00  01:00:00   02:00:00
1  B  00:30:00  00:20:00   00:50:00
2  C  00:40:00  00:30:00   01:10:00
3  D  00:20:00  00:40:00   01:00:00
4  E  00:30:00  00:20:00   00:50:00
```

---

```
df['total-time'] = df.filter(like='time').astype(str).apply(pd.to_timedelta).sum(axis=1)
```

---

```
df['total-time'] = df[['time1','time2']].astype(str).apply(pd.to_timedelta).sum(axis=1)
```