# How to add datetime.time object in pandas

Tags: python, datetime

I have a column which has datetime,time objects. I need to find average time, total time.

inp:

```
150    03:00:00
157    03:00:00
Name: col , dtype: object
```

their type:

```
<class 'datetime.time'>
```

I used

```
df["col"].sum()
```

but I didn't get the exact results

Comment: Btw. the dupe was the 1st hit on google of "python pandas sum time" - seems as if you need to sharpen your google-fu.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Convert values to strings and then timedeltas:

```
s = pd.to_timedelta(df["col"].astype(str))

out = s.sum()
print (out)
0 days 06:00:00
```

Comment: Seems as if that is a dupe of your answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38229878/7505395)